# How to find SMD transistors library for Altium Designer?

Tags: altium, surface-mount, library

I am new in PCB design, so excuse me if this is a bad question!
I know the basic electronics and how to draw schematics in Altium. But about SMD parts, I am a little confused! How can I find SMD transistors, diodes, resistors, inductors and capacitors? Is there any specific library for them? If not, how should I find them?

Comment: Use the symbols to draw your schematic. Then create your own footprint library and make your own footprints or use the IPC-complant footprint wizard that is built into Altium to generate them based on the dimensions provided in the datasheets.

Comment: So you say the only important thing is parts footprint and the footprint have standards(1206,0805,SOT223,Sot23,etc) and when a capacitor or resistor is in 1206 package, or a transistor in sot23 pack, it is not important is it from which company or what specifics(voltage, current, power,etc) do they have?

The only important thing when you design a PCB with SMD parts is the parts footprint, and footprints are same when you use a 0805 package resistor without attention to it's company, or voltage,power,etc!

Comment: I have no idea what you just asked because of your terrible grammar and punctuation. Can you please try to clarify using plain, correct English?

Comment: There are a few you can find online, but this was actually one of the reasons I switched to Kicad. Having libraries of digikey parts on GitHub is really nice.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest (and fastest) way is actually building up your own library. You could use the vault too, but don't ask me how that works ;).

Go to `File > New > Library > Schematic Library` to build a symbol library. If you open your *[library].SchLib* theres a handy wizard (`Tools > Symbol Wizard`).

Go to `File > New > Library > PCB Library` to build a footprint library. The two IPC Wizards you'll find in your *[library].PcbLib* under `Tools > IPC Compliant Footptrint ...` are, at least in my daily worklife on of the killer features of Altium.